# How to contain the drag n drop of a canvas inside another canvas?

Tags: javascript, html

What I mean is the inner canvas cannot move outside the outer canvas. I need to create a meter + progress bar like image. See image below.

According to the image below, the meter control should only be move up n down in that restricted region. I believe it can be done using drag and drop in HTML5?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here is a tutorial to drag and drop

http://simonsarris.com/blog/140-canvas-moving-selectable-shapes

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-an-image-tutorial/

Comment: do u hv eg tt doesn't use Kinetic and fully HTML5 DnD?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$(yourMeter).draggable({
axis: 'y',
containment: $(yourProgressBar)});
```

Comment: can hv eg using HTML5 DnD API (html5demos.com/drag) ?